# Can't install alongside WinXP

Tags: installation

Recently threw out older version of Ubuntu because of failure to connect to router.
Then decided to try 12.10. It connects easily.
Unfortunately I am not given the option to install alongside WinXP. Since the older version was so installed, I do not understand.

If I click the 'Install' icon on the desktop I get a message 'Installer has detected a mounted partition - .... unmount or not?'
I do not understand the significance of this.

Can anyone please help?

Terminal info is:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x06060605

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   312560639   156280288+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

---

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD1600AAJS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  160GB  160GB  primary  ntfs         boot

Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 0):

The mounted partition problem occurs usually when you have some memory card or some other memory devices inserted.
To install Ubuntu alongside with windows Xp do following:
First you should create a separate partition with the help of disk management tool in windows in which you can install Ubuntu.
Then after booting Ubuntu from USB/DVD, you should format the free space ext4 format.
At last install Ubuntu to this ext4 partition.
Use Wubi Installer, to easily install ubuntu alongside with windows.